# parent div with pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to make is a onepage website with a rating section. In this rating section I have a parent div were all the posts are placed in so like this:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="post">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="post">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="post">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="post">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

When the parent div contains 10 posts it should make a new page for the posts posted later.

EDIT:
It's just like tabs but it should automatically make a new tab per 10 posts.

Comment: how are you adding the content to parent-div??

Comment: I'm using the starReviews plugin from codecanyon http://codecanyon.net/item/starreviews-ajax-jquery-rating-and-review-form/6584956